# How to migrate existing unencryped realm DB to encrypt realm - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I have a React Native application in production using the Realm database, however, I want to encrypt the bank for security reasons, as I will add an external path.
However, I need to perform a bank migration, as I can't encrypt a bank that already exists because the relationships are different.

Someone could help with that item, I didn't find anything clear in the documentation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution creating an inline migration, the only struggle was that I couldn't persist the data because of the different structure, but at the moment it's fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsP8s.jpg)